# Convert multiple HTML files into CSV files

Tags: powershell

I have hundreds of HTML files in tabular format which needs to be converted to CSV. To do it manually, I'd be opening each HTML file in Excel and saving as *.CSV.
How can I automate this through PowerShell?

```
$FolderPath = 'C:\Users\abcd\Desktop\New folder'


$FilePaths = get-childitem $FolderPath -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".html"} 

foreach($FilePath in $FilePaths)
{
 Export-CSV -Path $FilePath
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might try this: [Read-HtmlTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Read-HtmlTable): `Get-Content -Raw $FilePath |Read-HtmlTable`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have HTML files that actually have CSV content is that correct? In that case you would only need to rename them from .html to .csv wouldn't you?

```
Move-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $filePath.Replace(".html", ".csv")
```

If not what exactly is the format of the "tabular format" in the source files? Can u provide example data from these HTML files?

Comment: If you directly change the extension from html to csv or xlsx it breaks the tabular formatting. Manually I can just open the html in Excel and save it as CSV. Formatting looks like this<html>    
<head>    
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
<title>Clash Report</title>    
<style>    
          body table {   
          font-family: Calibri  Tahoma  Verdana  Arial  sans-serif;
          }